# pecl install ampq failed

Tags: php, amqp

I want to create RabbitMQ clients and workers in PHP on my Ubuntu machine. These is the whole list of steps that I followed:

```
apt-get install aptitude
aptitude install libtool
aptitude install pkg-config
cd /tmp
rm -rf rabbitmq-c
git clone -b v0.5.2 git://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c.git
cd rabbitmq-c
autoreconf -i && ./configure && make && make install
pecl install amqp-1.4.0
```

I took these steps from [this](http://php.net/manual/fa/amqp.installation.php) thread. But when I run the last command, I get this error message:

> No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/apmq"

So, what is wrong with that?

PS. `PHP` version is `5.6.4`.

Comment: I'm not sure wat is going wrong, but you can also use a amqpclient written in PHP. https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib. Or is a pecl extension a hard requirement? And can you execute pecl list-channels and post the result here?

Comment: Just a side note, try at least version 1.6.1, there was a lot of job done in 1.6.0 and later (especially in 1.7.0). BC provided.

Comment: And can someone provide one to one mapping between PHP and RabbitMQ, at least for fresh versions? I mean what version of PHP is compatible with what version of RabbitMQ. Now it seems like I'm facing some incompatibility.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm php-amqp contributor. Any php-amqp verison will do the job. RabbitMQ uses AMQP 0.9.1 (AMQP 1.0 supported via plugin). php-amqp extension uses under the hood librabbitmq which stick also to AMQP 0.9.1. As to PHP version itself, PHP >= 5.3 required (but I guess it will work with 5.2 before 1.7.0, we drop 5.2 support due to end of it life). In 1.7.0 PHP 7 support added. This is all about php-amqp extension, with php-amqplib things may be different, but most of it versions also works with RabbitMQ.

Comment: A bit offtopic: If you have not hard requirements what php amqp implementation, give a try both. While php-amqp more performant, it is written in synchronous manner. php-amqplib written and async manner. AMQP protocol designed with async in mind, so from AMQP protocol point of view, php-amqplib fits better it model. On the other side, php-amqp extension fits better to PHP synchronous nature (which is today not actually true, e.g. react, aerys and so on). php-amqp also has persistent connections support which is very handy when serving http requests. You can also use both together.

Comment: @zaq178miami. Thank you very much for such informative comments! They are very useful!

Comment: As to original question, i suppose you have rights to install pecl extension (otherwise, try with sudo). Anyway, there are vagrant environment served with php-amqp (https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp#development) and while it is probably overkill, you can try it. It shipped with RabbitMQ and PHP and php-amqp dependencies on board, so you can even install any desired php-amqp version there. Or give a look on [provision.sh](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/blob/master/provision/provision.sh) script which configure environment and install necessary dependencies.